# Illustrator: trying to isolate some layers in a stock vector image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, images

I downloaded a stock vector image and I want to delete some of the layers but something strange is happening. Two of the main layers seem to be images as opposed to vector drawings and I can't seem to isolate some of the elements. I have released the mask and it doesn't do anything.

I can delete the one section of the horse on the left, but the other part seems to be attached to that whole section?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it's going to be pretty difficult to answer this question without examining the file (sharing it would violate the license). If it's not a clipping or opacity mask, it's almost impossible to guess at what it may be.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is layered then first go to the 'Layers' panel <kbd>F7</kbd>, unlock any locked layers and choose 'Flatten Artwork'.

Then select all via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, right click and choose 'Release Clipping Mask' as many times as you can or until it becomes clear that everything has been released from its mask.

Then you might also need to select all again and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> a few times to ungroup any groups that might be defined.

Then going into outline mode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> might be helpful to locate parts of the resulting released and ungrouped artwork. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> for the 'Direct Selection Tool' which allows you to select objects or paths individually and remove what you don't need.

Comment: I don't know Illustrator that well... I think that section was an imported image.

Comment: Only vectors have anchor points.